# Redis Queue Kill Job using JOB-ID

Tags: python, redis, python-rq

I used Python Flask+Redis and I queued the jobs at redis queue using the below code:

```
 with Connection(redis.from_url("redis://localhost:6379")):
            queue = Queue()
            task = queue.enqueue(self.redis_method, job_timeout=86400, result_ttl=604800, failure_ttl=604800)
            response_object = {"status": "success", "data": {"task_id": task.get_id()}}
            return response_object
```

Jobs are getting queued and execution starts and I get Job-id for queued job. And used below code to kill Job but the execution doesn't stop even after executing below code

```
cancel_job(job_id=job_id,connection= redis.from_url("redis://localhost:6379"))
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks in Advance~

Answer (score 1):

`cancel_job` removes the job from the queue. If it's already in the execution process you have to kill the worker.

```
from rq.command import send_kill_horse_command

send_kill_horse_command(connection, worker_name)
```